# How to add onAttach in adapter in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gu5eOgfbrSc&t=1050s) in order to create a reaction dialog but I get this error `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.app.Activities.MainActivity@cbb7134 at com.example.app.ReactionsPackage.ReactionsDialog.onAttach(ReactionsDialog.java:101)`.

This is my ReactionDialog:

```
public class ReactionsDialog extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    View view;
    ImageView like, love, haha, glimpse, wow;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_reactions, container, false);
        initializeComponents();
        return view;
    }

    private void initializeComponents() {
        if (getView() == null)return;
        like = getView().findViewById(R.id.likeReaction);
        love = getView().findViewById(R.id.loveReaction);
        haha = getView().findViewById(R.id.hahaReaction);
        glimpse = getView().findViewById(R.id.eyeCloseReaction);
        wow = getView().findViewById(R.id.wowReaction);

        //Set click listeners
        like.setOnClickListener(this);
        love.setOnClickListener(this);
        haha.setOnClickListener(this);
        glimpse.setOnClickListener(this);
        wow.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View getView() {
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.likeReaction:
                listener.onReactionSelected(0);
                getDialog().dismiss();
                break;
            case R.id.loveReaction:
                listener.onReactionSelected(1);
                getDialog().dismiss();
                break;
            case R.id.hahaReaction:
                listener.onReactionSelected(2);
                getDialog().dismiss();
                break;
            case R.id.eyeCloseReaction:
                listener.onReactionSelected(3);
                getDialog().dismiss();
                break;
            case R.id.wowReaction:
                listener.onReactionSelected(4);
                getDialog().dismiss();
                break;
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    public void setupDialog(@NonNull Dialog dialog, int style) {
        super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams manager = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        manager.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        manager.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        manager.dimAmount = 0.0f;
        dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        dialog.onBackPressed();
    }

    ReactionListener listener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            listener = (ReactionListener)activity;
        }catch (ClassCastException exception) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This is my ReactionListener:

```
public interface ReactionListener {
    void onReactionSelected(int reactionType);
}
```

And this is what I have done in my adapter:

```
holder.like.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                getReactionDialog();
                return false;
            }
        });

private DialogFragment getReactionDialog(){
        ReactionsDialog reactionsDialog = new ReactionsDialog();
        reactionsDialog.show(((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager(), reactionsDialog.getClass().getSimpleName());
        return reactionsDialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReactionSelected(int reactionType) {
        switch (reactionType) {
            case 0:
                Toast.makeText(context, "You liked the post.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(context, "You loved the post.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                Toast.makeText(context, "You hahahed the post.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 3:
                Toast.makeText(context, "You closed your eye to the post.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 4:
                Toast.makeText(context, "You wowed the post.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
```

I think the error shows up because I call the dialog from an adapter and not from activity as it is shown in the video. So, should I change something in the onAttach function? What should I do? Thanks in advance!! Any answer will be appreciated.

**EDIT:** I tried to delete the `onAttach` method and it shows up the dialog. However, there comes a new error. The new error is this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.app.ReactionsPackage.ReactionListener.onReactionSelected(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.app.ReactionsPackage.ReactionsDialog.onClick(ReactionsDialog.java:58)
```

I guess this means that I need the onAttach but I have to add something that is missing, right?

**EDIT 2:** I tried exactly the same code but in activity instead of adapter and it worked. So, as I can see the problem is somewhere in `onAttach` as it cannot be called from the adapter. So, what should I do instead of that? Any answer will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: ClassCast that means that you try to do something like Person p = new Person(); String a = (String)p; -> a Person doesn't have an is-a relationship with String, so you can't cast it. You'll need to check your code and remove the invalid cast

Comment: Where do you create your adapter?  It looks like you intend on the adapter to implement `ReactionListener` given the override of `onReactionSelected`.  If so then this line needs some work: `listener = (ReactionListener)activity;` - since an `Activity ` is not  a `ReactionListerner` then this won't work - without seeing more code I _guess_ what you want is to create the adapter (or have access to it) in the `ReactionsDialog` and then the `onAttach` either is not needed or you create the adapter there.  Once `listerner` is initialized to the adapter instance - it should be good.

Comment: @Stultuske I can't understand how that works. Can you please explain that with more details?

Comment: @Gardener What do you need to see? In the adapter I implement ReactionListener. What else do I have to do?

Comment: I'll ask it again: where do you create your adapter?  The `listener` variable should be assigned to the adapter you create.

Comment: @Gardener The adapter existed before I create the dialog because I have a recyclerview. However, If I understand what you mean I haven't created any function inside my dialog that activates the adapter.

Comment: Your fragment has clickable views which, if clicked, invoke the `listener` which it appears you intend to be the adapter (since you did not include all of the adapter code I can only assume it has an `implements ReactionListener`).  Given this the `listener` variable in the fragment _must_ be set to the adapter instance - which is why I'm asking where is the adapter created.

Comment: @Gardener So, if I understand you mean that I hav eto add the onAttach inside the adapter, right? The adapter is created in another file inside the app. I don't know what you mean with where it is created. I hope I answered your question.

Comment: After looking at video - it looks like you may have skipped a portion - at around 16:41 it shows the `MainActivity` implementing `ReactionsListener` - do you have that

Comment: @Gardener Yes, I have that in my adapter.

Comment: @Gardener Do you want to open a chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244940/discussion-between-brad-cruise-and-gardener).

Comment: @BradCruise it's no use trying to write more complex code if you don't understand the basics of the language. Start at the beginning.

Comment: @Stultuske Okay.